# How to pass data into jquery done()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page displaying multiple records, and I am trying to write a click handler to take care of submitting changes to individual records via an ajax post.  I am using done(), fail(), and always() to manage the results.

When an ajax call returns, I want to make some updates to the record that was submitted -- e.g. put up a saved message, re-enable the submit button for that record, etc. -- but I cannot do that unless I know the ID of the specific record that was submitted.

What I would like to do would be to pass the ID of the target record into the done() so the code within the done() could make the necessary changes to the record that originally called it.

This is my code, which shows what I am doing, but which will not work because the variable `target_id` has no value in those functions.  How do I pass that variable along to those functions?

```
$("#container").on("click", ".save-button", function(e) {

  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {return;}

  var button_html = $(this).html();
  $(this).html('Please wait...');
  $(this).addClass('disabled');

  var target_id = $(this).parents(".record-form").find("#record-id").val();

  var form_poster = $.post("user_form_submit.php", target_form.serialize());

  form_poster.done(function(response_object) {

    var result = response_object['result'];

    if (result=='success') {
      var alert_area = $("#" + target_id + " .alert-area").html("Record Updated");
    } else {
      var alert_area = $("#" + target_id + " .alert-area").html("Record Not Found");
    }

  });

  form_poster.fail(function() {
    var alert_area = $("#" + target_id + " .alert-area").html("An Error Occurred");
  });

  form_poster.always(function() {
    $("#" + target_id + " .save-button").removeClass('disabled');
    $("#" + target_id + " .save-button").html(button_html);
  });

});
```

Comment: `target_id` is defined in a higher scope, so it should have a value, are you sure that is the problem ?

Comment: sounds like you are duplicating ID's which by definition must be unique, otherwise could replace `$(this).parents(".record-form").find("#record-id")` with `$("#record-id")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working, I think the problem is with your `id` attributes, they need to be unique. This whole line:

```
var target_id = $(this).parents(".record-form").find("#record-id").val();
```

Could just be:

```
var target_id = $("#record-id").val();
```

But my guess is you have several elements with the id `record-id`, you should use a class instead.

Comment: Right on, thanks!  I was spinning my wheels, assuming it was a variable scope thing, and missed the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a streamlined version of your code. You are doing way too much useless boilerplate.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".save-button", function(e) {
  var $saveButton = $(this),
      $recordForm = $saveButton.closest(".record-form"),
      $alertArea = $recordForm.find(".alert-area");

  $saveButton.addClass('disabled').html('Please wait...');

  e.preventDefault();

  $.post("user_form_submit.php", $recordForm.serialize())
  .done(function(response_object) {
    var result = response_object['result'];
    if (result == "success") {
      $alertArea.html("Record Updated");
    } else {
      $alertArea.html("Record Not Found");
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
    $alertArea.html("An Error Occurred");
  })
  .always(function() {
    $saveButon.removeClass('disabled').html(button_html);
  });
});
```

note that

- The variables you set are preserved in closures, so your callback functions can access them (compare the use of `$alertArea` and `$saveButon`). You do not need to "pass anything in" in the first place.
- `.record-id` is a CSS class now, you cannot have multiple elements with the same HMTL ID in a document
- You should not need to build selectors from IDs anyway, there is always structural context you can use (via `closest()` and `find()`).
- Use `preventDefault()` so the form will not be submitted twice accidentally.

Comment: Thank you for your response and very useful advice.  Your bullet point one answers my primary question.  I had an error with multiple elements using the same ID and I had assumed THAT was why I could not access the variable I needed.  As soon as I fixed that problem, my code worked.  I definitely see your point about the "useless boilerplate" and will learn from your $alertArea and $saveButon examples!  I accepted Rusty Jeans' answer since he answered first and identified the same error that you did, and I don't have the reputation to Vote yours Up yet, but I would if I could.

Comment: @RickFree Never mind the upvote. Feedback like yours is worth just as much to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark as I have no means to test

Just set a variable `var context` as `this`

```
$("#container").on("click", ".save-button", function(e) {
  var context = this;

  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {return;}

  this.button_html = $(this).html();
  $(this).html('Please wait...');
  $(this).addClass('disabled');

  this.target_id = $("#record-id").val();

  this.form_poster = $.post("user_form_submit.php", target_form.serialize());


  this.form_poster.done(function(response_object) {

    var result = response_object['result'];

    if (result=='success') {
      var alert_area = $("#" + context.target_id + " .alert-area").html("Record Updated");
    } else {
      var alert_area = $("#" + context.target_id + " .alert-area").html("Record Not Found");
    }

  });

  this.form_poster.fail(function() {
    var alert_area = $("#" + context.target_id + " .alert-area").html("An Error Occurred");
  });

  this.form_poster.always(function() {
    $("#" + context.target_id + " .save-button").removeClass('disabled');
    $("#" + context.target_id + " .save-button").html(button_html);
  });
```

Here's a proof of concept: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68a8K/)

This method is probably faster since you only need to call jQuery once to get the `target_id`

Comment: Christopher -- Thanks much for that example.  My mistake was dumb, but you showed me something super-useful and I learned a new trick.  Much appreciated!